# How to list All iPhone Apps By a SIngle developer in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-sdk

In My Application I want show all my iPhone apps from itunes store in a tableview. If user clicks any one of cell it leads to take to appstore of that application.I know just statically by giving link of each application. As per my need i need to get new apps also after this installation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `search` web service provided by Apple: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching

I couldn't find a way to search by artist ID for software, but you can still perform a generic query using the developer name.

For example, this would return apps by Gameloft:

http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Gameloft&media=software&lang=en_US&country=us

Note that it's a query by name,so you can have false positives (apps where the name *Gameloft* appears but are not real Gameloft apps). You have to check the `artistId` property for each returned app (in this case, Gameloft's artistId is 282764297).

If you want to open the App Store to a specific app, use the `trackId` you got from the previous web service and then

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:
  [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%d",
   trackId]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing your own table view, you can also use StoreKit to display the apps, and let the user purchase other apps right there.
Just replace 383916386 with the correct id for your developer account.

```
    SKStoreProductViewController *viewCtrl = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    [viewCtrl loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: @"383916386"} completionBlock:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```