# How to list all my apple developer portal apps

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to show all my itunes app listed to user.

I have button called More Apps . So i want to redirect it to App Store to show all my apps to user.

How to show this list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing all installed apps on iPhone Programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332369/listing-all-installed-apps-on-iphone-programmatically)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519716/how-to-list-all-iphone-apps-by-a-single-developer-in-iphone-app Please follow this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect Url is Possible , By Which You can redirect to app store like ,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appstore.com/gameloft"]];
```

You can take look at  [Apple Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1633/_index.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also display your App Store page right inside your app with StoreKit. Just replace `383916386` with the correct id for your developer account.

```
        SKStoreProductViewController *viewCtrl = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
        [viewCtrl loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: @"383916386"} completionBlock:nil];
        [self presentViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -2):

Get your "More App By this developer" url from browser (I have checked this code, it worked fine for me)

```
let itunesUrl = "itms://MORE_APP_BY_THIS_DEVELOPER_URL"

guard let url = URL(string: itunesUrl) else { return }

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

in Objective-C

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://MORE_APP_BY_THIS_DEVELOPER_URL"]];
```

For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/in/developer/aol-inc./id281704577"]];
```